# How to install third-party libraries (say opencv) with yum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-ec2, yum

I am very new to the `yum` package system, so please forgive my rookie question.

I am using an Amazon Linux AMI on EC2, would like to install a package, say `opencv` with `yum`:

```
$ sudo yum install opencv
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                          | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                       | 2.3 kB     00:00
No package opencv available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

It appears the repository `yum` knows does not contain a `opencv` distribution. I am wondering whether there is a way to tell `yum` to find this package at certain third-party repository, and if so, is there a good place to search for repository that contains particular packages? Any pointer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you find opencv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if epel repo is disabled by running:

```
sudo yum repolist all
```

If you see epel is disabled, then enable it and search:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel search opencv
```

If you find it, then install it. If you don't find it, you may to download the source, build and install it. Should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, @helloV. I enabled the EPEL repo, but cannot find opencv. I am able to build and install from source, but would still like to find a way to install the package directly, if possible. This [link](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/opencv-core) suggests Fedora 19-21 contains the package, any way I can add the repo to yum and install the package from there? Thanks!